# split a image into 2 parts in python

Tags: python, image

I want to split a 1600*256 image into 2 equal parts and then convert it to JSON using python and send it to cloud via MQTT and then again stitch it back.Any suggestions and code samples on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts.

1. split image in 2 parts

> ```
> import numpy as np
> from PIL import Image
> img = np.asarray(Image.open('/path/to/img.jpg'))
> img1 = img[0:800,0:128]
> img2 = img[800:,128:]
> ```

2. send it as json
   You can send it numpy array as string by decoding it by base64

> ```
> import base64
> json.dumps({"img1":str(base64.encodebytes(img1.tobytes()))})
> ```

again this is not correct way of encoding and sending image via json, please google for more correct ways.